# UWP Background task timers

Tags: xaml, timer, background-process, windows-10, uwp

I am working on an app that needs a timer to fire at a specified time in the background.  I then want to start a timer that ticks every 10 minutes or so till a specified time.  In all this I do not want the user to have to open the app.  What is the best way to achieve this?  I have looked around and haven't found a good, straight forward, answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> I then want to start a timer that ticks every 10 minutes or so till a specified time.

Windows has a built-in timer that runs background tasks in 15-minute intervals.
You can create a timer trigger to start the background process in a specific interval.

For details, please check the document [Run a background task on a timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt186458.aspx).

Comment: That's only every 15 minutes though, the requester was asking for every 10 minutes.